# Alarming number of questions (related)

Tags: discussion, questions

Related to the [alarm about a large number of edits](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2299/alarming-number-of-edits)...

I want to ask a second question in the last five minutes.  Would that be considered rude?

Hypothetically, what if I asked 35 questions tonight, which floods out / pushes down other peoples'?  **Would this be considered rude or abusive** with the WB crowd?  And why?  Or, could it be seen as a treat for question-hungry people.

Just curious.

Answer (score 5):

It might be only my opinion, but, especially if those questions are related, I would give it a bit of time in between. Like (at least) one a day or something like that.

There are at least a few reasons for that

1. As you perfectly mentioned, a question spree would push all other questions away, which is kind of unfair,
2. You should try to have high-quality questions, and that is hardly achievable in 5 minutes,
3. Give a bit of time for the community to assimilate your question. There may be some need to clarify some points (e.g. rules of magic), and it would be a waste to do it on all your questions at once,
4. The first answers to the first questions, may change your point of view on the following questions, change the order, add another one, etc. The answers are some kind of feed back, which you can profit from it. If you intend to write a series of books, you usually like to have some feed back on the first one before writing the many 1500-paged books,
5. No-one can probably find the time to answer 35 questions in the same day. Most people are busy otherwise and have to share their time between different questions,
6. People would get bored by the 5th, and no-one would have a look past the 15th.

Comment: +1 I'm definitely not going to be able to post 35 questions, but just sounding out how selfish it would be to post (even unrelated) multiple questions.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Post as many questions as you like. If they are unrelated then there is no reason to wait (unless you really are posting a huge number in which case it might be polite to slow down).

If they are related we recommend waiting between each one but that is for your benefit not ours as described in Bilbo's answer.